# Change font size on tabpages ('guitablabel') on vim?

Tags: tabs, vim

I'm using gVim on a linux machine, and would like to have smaller fonts on my tabpages (`guitablabel`). How do I change the font sizeonly on tabpages(tabs)?

Now, my config is

```
set guitablabel=%t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test in Ubuntu shows me that this is determined by your theme preferences, not by gvim.

To clarify, I mean GTK theme (or whatever Ubuntu's appearance preferences change), not vim colorscheme or anything like that.